# SizeToFit Navigation Bar Item (UITextField)

Tags: iphone, uitextfield, uinavigationbar

How do I size a UITextField to fit the whole UINavigationBar? So far I have this:

```
    locationField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(37,7,246,31)];
    locationField.delegate = self;
    locationField.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    locationField.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:102.0/255 green:102.0/255 blue:102.0/255 alpha:1.0];
    locationField.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    locationField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    locationField.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:15];
    locationField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    locationField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
```

I basically want to turn `locationField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(37,7,246,31)];` to fit the UINavigationBar, probably using `sizeToFit`, just not 100% sure how to implement it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the

```
[self.navigationItem setTitleView:locationField];
```

See code below:

```
    UITextField *locationField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(37,7,246,31)];
    locationField.delegate = self;
    locationField.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    locationField.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:102.0/255 green:102.0/255 blue:102.0/255 alpha:1.0];
    locationField.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    locationField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    locationField.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:15];
    locationField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    locationField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
    [self.navigationItem setTitleView:locationField];
    [locationField release];
```

Comment: it works for me to add a UITextField to NavigationBar~~ thans Dianz

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, got it fixed by switching the CGRect from:

```
UITextField *locationField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(37,7,246,31)];
```

to

```
UITextField *locationField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(37,7,300,31)];
```